# Eloquent create doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

A have a problem in creating in a table using Eloquent :

```
| id    | url         | shortened |
| 1     | website.com | asdf      |
```

So I want to insert a new URL , so I created a new model extending Eloquent then I wrote this :

```
$row = Url::create(array('url' => $url, 'shortened' => $shortened));
if ($row) {
    $both = array('url' => $url, 'shortened' => $row->shortened);
    return View::make('home.result', $both);
}
```

But when I try it , a problem happens : "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."
After that , I tried a new way :

```
$new_u = new Url();
$new_u->url = $url;
$new_u->shortened = $shortened;
$new_u->save();
```

With this in the Url class :

```
protected $table = 'urls';
protected $fillable = array('url', 'shortened');
```

And the same problem !

Comment: Can you check the contents of $url and $shortened?

Comment: the url is from input::get('url') , so it's a text . and the shortened is a random of sequence of characters ! By the way what is the function to convert to string , just to be sure :)

Comment: You can cast it to string: $bar = (string) $foo; Are you sure that $url and $shortened are being set and aren't empty?

Comment: @Hassan I tried the (string) function, but nothing changed! Yeah I'm sure that they are been set !

Comment: I know you mentioned what's in the url class, but could you show us the model in it's entirety?

Comment: Whoops, I did it ! It must the $timestamps is set false !
Thanks @Hassan for your time

Comment: No problemo, glad you figured it out.

Comment: @user3681724 Please mark this question as solved if everything is now working fine for you :)